# WHERE Statement to find all records in a month?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I want to find all of the records involved in June!

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
CaseID  StartDate   EndDate
1       2016-05-31  2016-06-01
2       2016-02-29  2016-06-20 
3       2016-03-21  2016-06-01 
4       2016-05-05  2016-06-01 
5       2016-05-20  2016-07-01 
6       2016-05-12  2016-12-31
```

```
SELECT CaseID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM ServiceCase
WHERE((StartDate > '2016-05-31' and StartDate < '2016-07-01') or  (EndDate > 
'2016-05-31' and EndDate < '2016-07-01'))
```

**But I cannot search CaseID 6's Record, Am I Logic wrong?**

Comment: Simple, record 6 doesn't match your criteria. Since neither the start nor end date is in June.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen How can i  make this statement can search item 6?

Comment: You have provided start date in condition which I think you should not, as it strictly checking that start date should greater than 2016-05-31 but your start date 2016-05-12 is earlier than this one

Comment: What is your expected result, all of the sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to select all cases that were in progress during the month of June. If so, then these are the 4 possible scenarios:

[image]

Or, in other words, the cases would have to both

- start before July; and
- end after May

So, the query would essentially look like this:

```
SELECT CaseID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM ServiceCase
WHERE
    StartDate < '2016-07-01' AND EndDate > '2016-05-31'
```

Output: [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a064dd/1)

Comment: End after may can be June, July, August.... December also, he wants record of single month June only here

Comment: @Rupal No, OP wants to have cases that were "involved" in June. The question specifically states that case 6 should be part of the output.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: If you go with `>= 2016/06/01` then you don't need to know the number of days in the preceding month

Answer (score 0):

Try as mentioned below:

```
SELECT CaseID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM ServiceCase
WHERE(StartDate < '2016-07-01' and EndDate > '2016-05-31')
```

Comment: Your query will happily output even cases that started and ended in January.

Comment: Your updated query will still not have case 6 as part of the result set.

Comment: Agreed, but am still not sure that he wants records which are not belongs to june even, as I written comment in your answer, it will gives record of month after june also. correct me if am wrong

Comment: So now, you have just copied my query? Without attribution?

Comment: No I didn't, I followed your last comment which was correct and make me thought to correct logic which I did, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MySQL [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) Function; sample code as bellow for the month June

```
SELECT CaseID, StartDate, EndDate
  FROM ServiceCase
 WHERE MONTH(StartDate) = 6
    OR MONTH(EndDate) = 6
    OR (MONTH(StartDate) < 6 AND MONTH(EndDate) > 6)
```

**Note:** this is just an option to compare **month** part without considering performance.

Comment: **@DownVoter** could you explain why?